# What is better to use just one method with switch or 4 different methods?

Tags: java

I have a object and i get some fields from it, i made a method with a switch statement, the idea was make it generic and just call this method through parameters but now I´m not sure.

The options are

```
private String getCode(Row row, String code) {
    String result;
    switch (code) {
      case code1:
        result = row.getString("constant1");
        break;
      case code2:
        result = row.getString(constant2);
        break;
      case code3:
        result = row.getString(constant3);
        break;
      case code4:
        result = row.getString(constant4);
        break;
      default:
        result = null;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

or

```
private String getcode1(Row row){
    return row.getString("constant1")
  }

  private String getcode1(Row row){
    return row.getString("constant2")
  }
  private String getcode1(Row row){
    return row.getString("constant3")
  }

  private String getcode1(Row row){
    return row.getString("constant4")
  }
```

I wand to use the better way, I´m a little confuse

Comment: Why not `row.getString(code)`?

Comment: you don't need a `switch` declaration just make a function like this: `private String getCode(Row row, String code) {  return row.getString(code); }`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I could do it, the point is which option its better because I´m gonna end up calling the same times a method but one with a switch

Comment: @Teocci the idea is if i know what method I´m gonna call I know the value and thats why it is a constant

Comment: Option 3: A `HashMap` associating codes to constants.

Comment: @Jose what are the type of values? you want to return a `String` that is clear, `getString()` receives an `String` also, right? and `code` is also String, right? I need to know if the `code` is not the same as the constants also.

Comment: @Teocci they are the same, i know when I had to call each method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is neither of the them.

What you have here is a value conversion process. **How this works?** Well, as far I understand, you need to store the data in form of `key`-`value` pair where `key` must be unique. So this is the definition of a `HashMap` in java.

Also, because you are using `Switch` I'm assuming that you can identify your data with some unique key. This meas for each `code` there is only one `constant`. **But how we can apply this to my issue?** Well, I think you have a collection of data from where you extracted a single `row`. Now, from this `row` you want to access to a value (lets call it `codeValue`) using a `constant`, but to get this `constant` you need a `code`. Like this:  `code->constant->codeValue`

#### How can I implement this??

Well, we gonna need a `HasMap()` called `constants`, which defines its keys a `codes` and the values as `constants`. Now you easily get each `constant` if you know its `code`. Obviously, if you get the `constant` you can also get the `codeValue` of each `row, like this:

```java
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a HashMap object called constants
        Map<String, String> constants = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // Add keys and values (code, constant)
        constants.put("code1", "constant1");
        constants.put("code2", "constant2");
        constants.put("code3", "constant3");
        constants.put("code4", "constant4");

        System.out.println(constants); 

        Row row  = loadRow();
        String code = loadCode();

        //How to use it
        String result = getCodeValue(row, code);

        System.out.println(result); 
    }


    // Now you get the code from the Map
    private String getCodeValue(Row row, String code) {
        return row.getString(constants.get(code));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case your input code is different than constant, I will suggest the following approach. Create an Enum mapping code and constant.

```
public enum Mapping {
    MAPPING_FIRST("code1", "constant1"),
    MAPPING_SECOND("code2", "constant2");

    private String code;
    private String constant;

    // constructor and getters

    public static Mapping getMappingFromCode(String code){
       return Arrays.stream(Mapping.values())
          .filter(mapping -> mapping.getCode().equals(code))
          .findFirst()
          .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Now, create a method to access value from row.

```
private String getValue(Row row, String code) {
   Mapping mapping = Mapping.getMappingFromCode(code);

   if(mapping == null){
      return null;
   }
   return row.getString(mapping.getConstant());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is little bit to much, but I will try to explain best I could. For me second option is no no at all. Why? You are making methods that you will have to sort out with some if/else statements anyway, for example:

```
if (code.equals(code1))
    someString = getcode1(row);
else if (code.equals(code2))
    somestring = getcode2(row);
else if (code.equals(code3))
    someString = getcode3(row);
else
    someString = getcode4(row);
```

Why not use this:

```
if (code.equals(code1))
    someString = row.getString("content1");
else if (code.equals(code2))
    somestring = row.getString("content2");
else if (code.equals(code3))
    someString = row.getString("content3");
else
    someString = row.getString("content4");
```

The first one I can see being used, but there is alternative there. Give us entire minimal requirement code with entire class and methods and we could help you far more than using these snippets of code.

Answer (score 0):

Create an enum for mapping of code and constant. In that enum, create a generic method where you can get code just passing through parameter.

```
public enum MyEnum {

    CODE1("constant1"), CODE2("constant2");

    private String constant;

    public String getConstant() {
        return constant;
    }

    private MyEnum(String constant) {
        this.constant = constant;
    }

    private static String getConstant(String code) {
        return Arrays.stream(MyEnum.values()).filter(mapping -> mapping.name().equalsIgnoreCase(code))
                .map(e -> e.getConstant()).findAny().orElse(null);
    }

    public static String getCode(Row row, String code) {
        String constant = getConstant(code);
        return constant != null ? row.get(constant) : null;

    }

}
```

You can get code from row object by calling genric method **getCode()**.

```
MyEnum.getCode(row, "code1")
```

Comment: how this is different than the my answer to this question?

Comment: Almost same just added a generic method to enum which he wants

Comment: This is a copy of the @lucid solution, you don't even explain why did u use an `enum`. The user asked I have two methods which one is the best and you answered *create this..*, why???